# filter out rows preceding a specific condition

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have the following dataset:

```
ID<-rep(c("A","B"),times=c(3,4))
Departure<-c("TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE")
Date<-c("Jan 1","Jan 2","Jan 3","Jan 1","Jan 2","Jan 3","Jan 4")

data<-data.frame(ID,Departure,Date)
data

ID Departure  Date
A      TRUE Jan 1
A     FALSE Jan 2
A      TRUE Jan 3
B      TRUE Jan 1
B     FALSE Jan 2
B     FALSE Jan 3
B      TRUE Jan 4
```

I want to subset this dataset using the following two conditions:

1. The dataset must only keep the rows **after** and **including** the last FALSE value in the "departure" column.
2. Condition 1 must be fulfilled within each ID.

The resulting dataset would look like this:

```
    ID Departure  Date

A     FALSE Jan 2
A      TRUE Jan 3
B     FALSE Jan 3
B      TRUE Jan 4
```

Any suggestions regarding how to do this, preferably using dplyr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a fun challenge! I'm sure you can come up with something smarter, but this is what I have (using `dplyr`):

```
group_by(data, ID) %>% mutate(row=1:n(), 
                              rowF=ifelse(Departure==F, row, NA), 
                              maxF=max(rowF, na.rm=T)) %>% 
  filter(row >= maxF) %>% 
  select(-c(row:maxF)) %>%  
  # remove the above line if you want to see how the sausage was made
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  ID    Departure Date 
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>
1 A     FALSE     Jan 2
2 A     TRUE      Jan 3
3 B     FALSE     Jan 3
4 B     TRUE      Jan 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R

```
data[
  ave(as.logical(data$Departure),data$ID,FUN=function(x){
    t=cumsum(!x)
    t==max(t)
  }),
]

  ID Departure  Date
2  A     FALSE Jan 2
3  A      TRUE Jan 3
6  B     FALSE Jan 3
7  B      TRUE Jan 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `data.table`

**note** I prepared your data, use a logical TRUE/FALSE and I used dates instead of month day strings.

**data**

```
ID <- rep(c("A","B"),times=c(3,4))
Departure <- as.logical(c("TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE"))
Date <- lubridate::parse_date_time(c("Jan 1","Jan 2","Jan 3","Jan 1","Jan 2","Jan 3","Jan 4"), "md")

data <- data.frame(ID, Departure, Date)
```

**solution**

First we take a subset of your last FALSE records per ID, we then join those results back on all records with a more recent date.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

results <- data[!Departure, .SD[.N], ID][data, .(ID, Departure = i.Departure, Date), on = .(ID, Date <= Date), nomatch = 0]
```

**Results**

```
results

   ID Departure       Date
1:  A     FALSE 2023-01-02
2:  A      TRUE 2023-01-03
3:  B     FALSE 2023-01-03
4:  B      TRUE 2023-01-04
```

**extended**

If you really want to get your Date formats as they were, simply format them afterwards again

```
results[, Date := format(Date, "%b %d")]

results

   ID Departure   Date
1:  A     FALSE Jan 02
2:  A      TRUE Jan 03
3:  B     FALSE Jan 03
4:  B      TRUE Jan 04
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on the data you have provided, though I am unsure if it would work on other examples (it is unclear to me the rules around IDs - so you may want to check this, but it should work:

```
df %>% 
mutate(Departure = ifelse(Departure == "TRUE", TRUE, FALSE)) %>% # change the Departure column to logical, not character
filter((Departure == TRUE & lag(Departure) == FALSE & ID == lag(ID)) | (Departure == FALSE & lead(Departure) == TRUE & lead(Departure) != FALSE) & ID == lead(ID))
# if the departure is TRUE and the previous departure is FALSE and the ID is the same as the previous ID, 
# or 
# if the departure is FALSE and the next departure is TRUE and the next departure is not FALSE and the ID is the same as the next ID, #then keep the row

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  ID    Departure Date 
  <chr> <lgl>     <chr>
1 A     FALSE     Jan 2
2 A     TRUE      Jan 3
3 B     FALSE     Jan 3
4 B     TRUE      Jan 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the sum of the negated Departure column is equal to the cumsum of the negated departure column.  Note that this column in your example data is character and needs to be changed to logical:

```
library(dplyr)

data |>
  mutate(Departure = as.logical(Departure)) |>
  filter(sum(!Departure) == cumsum(!Departure) & any(!Departure), .by = ID)

  ID Departure  Date
1  A     FALSE Jan 2
2  A      TRUE Jan 3
3  B     FALSE Jan 3
4  B      TRUE Jan 4
```

I'm unsure if you need `& any(!Departure)` in the filter conditions but this will ensure that only groups that contain `FALSE` values are retained.

Answer (score 1):

Using `rev`resed `rle` `by` ID.

```
by(data, data$ID, \(x) tail(x, with(rle(rev(x$Departure)), which.max(values == 'FALSE')))) |>
  do.call(what='rbind')
#     ID Departure  Date
# A.2  A     FALSE Jan 2
# A.3  A      TRUE Jan 3
# B.6  B     FALSE Jan 3
# B.7  B      TRUE Jan 4
```

Note, that if the Departure column would be true boolean,

```
data$Departure <- as.logical(data$Departure)
```

it simplifies to

```
by(data, data$ID, \(x) tail(x, with(rle(rev(x$Departure)), which.max(!values)))) |>
  do.call(what='rbind')
```