# Subsetting series of rows with specific pattern

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have the following dataset:

```
ID Departure  Date
A      TRUE Jan 1
A     FALSE Jan 2
A      TRUE Jan 3
A     FALSE Jan 4
A     FALSE Jan 5
A     FALSE Jan 6
A     FALSE Jan 7
A      TRUE Jan 8
A     FALSE Jan 9
B      TRUE Jan 1
B     FALSE Jan 2
B     FALSE Jan 3
B     FALSE Jan 4
B      TRUE Jan 5
```

I want to subset successive rows where the departure column has the following pattern: "TRUE", "FALSE","FALSE","FALSE".

The resulting dataset should look like this:

```
 ID Departure  Date
  
    A      TRUE Jan 3
    A     FALSE Jan 4
    A     FALSE Jan 5
    A     FALSE Jan 6
    B      TRUE Jan 1
    B     FALSE Jan 2
    B     FALSE Jan 3
    B     FALSE Jan 4
```

Is there any way of doing this in R, preferably using dplyr?

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Departure = c("TRUE", "FALSE", 
"TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", 
"TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE"), Date = c("Jan 1", 
"Jan 2", "Jan 3", "Jan 4", "Jan 5", "Jan 6", "Jan 7", "Jan 8", 
"Jan 9", "Jan 1", "Jan 2", "Jan 3", "Jan 4", "Jan 5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Comment: May I ask why you are [constantly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76537107/6574038) using strings `"TRUE"` instead of booleans `TRUE`?

Comment: PS: I used `dput(data)` to edit your question, it's the way we share data here and provides more focus on your actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I don't have a lot of experience with R yet, so I didn't understand the difference between strings and booleans. I also didn't know how to used dput(data), I'll be doing that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

data |> 
  group_by(ID) |> 
  mutate(pattern = (Departure == "TRUE" & lead(Departure) == "FALSE" & lead(Departure, n = 2) == "FALSE" & lead(Departure, n = 3) == "FALSE")) |> 
  filter(pattern | lag(pattern) | lag(pattern, n = 2) | lag(pattern, n = 3)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  select(-pattern)

# A tibble: 8 × 3
  ID    Departure Date 
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>
1 A     TRUE      Jan 3
2 A     FALSE     Jan 4
3 A     FALSE     Jan 5
4 A     FALSE     Jan 6
5 B     TRUE      Jan 1
6 B     FALSE     Jan 2
7 B     FALSE     Jan 3
8 B     FALSE     Jan 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You could paste Departures to a binary string and use `regexpr` in a `by` like so.

```
by(data, data$ID, \(x) {
  re <- regexpr('1000', paste(+as.logical(x$Departure), collapse=''))
  x[seq.int(re, re + attr(re, 'match.length') - 1), ]
}) |> do.call(what='rbind')
#      ID Departure  Date
# A.3   A      TRUE Jan 3
# A.4   A     FALSE Jan 4
# A.5   A     FALSE Jan 5
# A.6   A     FALSE Jan 6
# B.10  B      TRUE Jan 1
# B.11  B     FALSE Jan 2
# B.12  B     FALSE Jan 3
# B.13  B     FALSE Jan 4
```

`paste(+as.logical(x$Departure), collapse='')` transforms your column into a string such as `"101000010"`, `regexpr` yields the first match of `1000` and `attr(., 'match.length')` the match length where we subtract `1` to create a respectivce `seq`uence.

---

*Data:*

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Departure = c("TRUE", "FALSE", 
"TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", 
"TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE"), Date = c("Jan 1", 
"Jan 2", "Jan 3", "Jan 4", "Jan 5", "Jan 6", "Jan 7", "Jan 8", 
"Jan 9", "Jan 1", "Jan 2", "Jan 3", "Jan 4", "Jan 5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```